# is there a way to write a one liner if-statement, involving for-statement on all items based on a specific value == False?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to find an effective condition statement which executes code.

I am looking at something along the lines of,

```
if for all in list[1]['purchased'] == False:
    main()
```

I Have items inside a list which are all nested lists.
Each nested list consists of two dictionaries, whereby the 2nd dictionary has a KEY "purchased". this is consistent for every item in the main list.

Example:

```
Main_list = [[{'time': str, 'price': int},{'name': "Bob", 'stock purchased': bool}], 
[{'time': str, 'price': int}, {'name': "Bob", 'stock purchased': bool}]]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

kindest regards,
Andrew

Answer (score 3):

like this? `if all(not l[1]['stock purchased'] for l in list):`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Comment: That's it! thank you :) on an else statement, is there an effective way to quickly pick out the item in a list which is equalling True? or would it just be a standard for loop?

Comment: If you are using Python 3.8, you can do something like `if all(not (x := l[1]['stock purchase']) for l in list)`, where `x` is repeated set to the value being tested. Once `all` returns, `x` is either the first `True` value or the last item in the list, and the return value of `all` will tell you which is the case.

Comment: just tested that piece of code, I changed a item's value to True to test it. with a print method of 'x' to show the relevant nested list. I ran the code and it resulted in a blank output with no errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
if not any(list[1]["purchased"])
```

Nevermind, see @Kevin's answer